# Liferay 6.2 Search result on separate page

Tags: search, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-velocity

Is it possible to redirect search-Result (portlet: **$theme.journalContentSearch()**    ) to my "**http://localhost/search**" page?

I need this, because on home-page I don't have any portlets-placeholder, and after submit search-form, I see nothing. If I use this function on other page, it work fine, but stay in same page where I do form-submit, e.g. "/contact?****blablabla****"

```
/* new */
long searchPlid = plid;
System.out.println(TAG + "plid: " + plid);
//My Hidden search page
Layout searchPage = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.fetchLayoutByFriendlyURL(group.getGroupId(), false, "/search");
if (null != searchPage) {
    searchPlid = searchPage.getPlid();    
    System.out.println(TAG + "searchPlid. " + searchPlid);
}
/* /new */


if (portletResponse != null) {
    LiferayPortletResponse liferayPortletResponse = (LiferayPortletResponse)portletResponse;
    //portletURL = liferayPortletResponse.createLiferayPortletURL(PortletKeys.SEARCH, PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
    portletURL = liferayPortletResponse.createLiferayPortletURL(searchPlid, PortletKeys.SEARCH, PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
}
else {
    //portletURL = new PortletURLImpl(request, PortletKeys.SEARCH, plid, PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
    portletURL = new PortletURLImpl(request, PortletKeys.SEARCH, searchPlid, PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
}
```

this doesn't work, because I stay in same page after submit form :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344584/how-to-redirect-search-page-liferay-6-2/35014512#35014512

Comment: I think your solution is a bit other, what I needed... But thank you!

Comment: Is this not sufficient for your case?