# How to redirect search page liferay 6.2?

Tags: liferay-6

Is it possible to redirect search-Result (portlet: `$theme.journalContentSearch()` ) to another my page (example "/search")?

In `.../taglib/ui/search/start.jsp`
I have tried to change:

```
portletURL.setParameter("redirect", currentURL);
```

in

```
portletURL.setParameter("redirect", "/results");
```

But didn't work. Have you any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745208/liferay-6-2-search-result-on-separate-page

Answer (score 0):

> I know, this is an outdated question. But, today I had similar task to do
>   and here are my findings.

Unfortunately, there isn't any configuration option available to redirect and show search results on desired page.

However, I solved it with following custom `jQuery` hack:

```
if(jQuery('#p_p_id_77_') != null && jQuery('#p_p_id_77_').length > 0){
    var URL = jQuery('#p_p_id_77_').find('form').attr('action');

    var startURL = URL.substring(0, URL.lastIndexOf('/'));
    var middleURL = "/search";  // Page where you want to redirect and show search results
    var endURL = URL.substring(URL.indexOf('?'), URL.length);

    var finalURL = startURL + middleURL + endURL;
    jQuery('#p_p_id_77_').find('form').attr('action', finalURL);
}
```

And this is my `HTML` part of `portal_normal.vm`

```
<div class="top-header-search">
    #set ($searchPortletId = "77")
    $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portlet-setup-show-borders", "false")
    #set($restoreRenderingPortletContent = $theme.runtime($searchPortletId, "", $velocityPortletPreferences.toString()))
    $restoreRenderingPortletContent
    $velocityPortletPreferences.reset()
</div>
```

I preferred embedding search portlet using `$theme.runtime`, because I observed that using `$theme.journalContentSearch()` redirection part is working fine, but it is returning everything in search, as `keyword` of header field is not being passed to search results field.